# Qiskit TwoLocal does not print Quantum Circuit

Tags: python, printing, qiskit

I am using a VQE algorithm for which I am using the TwoLocal fucntion. I am however not able to print the circuit as it gives a very weird picture of the circuit.

````
ry.draw('mpl')```

Here is the code i am using to simulate the Quantum circuit



[The output that i get when i print my cicuit is ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHLds.png
````

Comment: ry = TwoLocal(8, "ry", "cz", reps=2, entanglement="full")

ry.draw('mpl')


this is my circuit and i need to print it

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a single multi-qubit gate that says TwoLocal, because that is how Qiskit represents that operation abstractly:

```py
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
ry = TwoLocal(8, "ry", "cz", reps=2, entanglement="full")
ry.draw('mpl')
```

[image: TwoLocal drawing, as a block]

If you want to "decompose" (break that operation in more basic operation), you can run the method `decompose()`

```py
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
ry = TwoLocal(8, "ry", "cz", reps=2, entanglement="full").decompose()
ry.draw('mpl')
```

[image: TwoLocal decomposition]